# Capybara doesn't want to select an input node

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, poltergeist

My HTML/ERB looks like this

```
<fieldset class="row notifications">
    <legend>
        <hr class="dash blue inline">
        <%= t :my_notifications %>
    </legend>

    <label>
        <%= f.check_box(:subscribed_to_news) %>
        <span></span>
        <span class="checkbox-text"><%= t :accepts_to_receive_news %></span>
        <br>
    </label>
</fieldset>
```

When I debug my Cucumber test with Capybara, I do find the notification checkbox `f.check_box(:subscribed_to_news)` in this mess

```
page.find('.notifications label')['innerHTML']
# => "\n\t\t<input name=\"user[subscribed_to_news]\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"0\"><input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"1\" checked=\"checked\" name=\"user[subscribed_to_news]\" id=\"user_subscribed_to_news\">\n\t\t<span></span>\n\t\t<span class=\"checkbox-text\">blahblahblah</span>\n\t\t<br>\n\t"
```

But for some reason I cannot find the nested inputs nor find them by ID

```
page.find('.notifications label input') 
# => Capybara::ElementNotFound Exception: Unable to find css ".notifications label input"
page.find('.notifications label #user_subscribed_to_news') # => Capybara::ElementNotFound Exception: Unable to find css ".notifications label #user_subscribed_to_news"
```

Selecting the label does work though

```
page.find('.notifications label')
# => #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="label" path="//HTML[1]/BODY[1]/DIV[1]/MAIN[1]/SECTION[1]/FORM[1]/FIELDSET[3]/LABEL[1]">
```

What am I doing wrong ? I just want to check the damn checkbox :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that the checkbox is unreachable via normal css /xpath...

I got away using some javascript

```
page.execute_script(%Q{document.querySelector('#{area} input##{selector}').click()})
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely reason is the checkbox is actually hidden by CSS and then replaced with images to enable identical styling of checkboxes across different browsers.  If you're using the latest Capybara you can have it click it the label when the checkbox is hidden by calling

```
page.check('user_subscribed_to_news', allow_label_click: true) # you can also set Capybara.automatic_label_click = true to default to this behavior
```

or if using an older capybara you would need to click the label yourself

```
page.find(:label, "blahblahblah").click #match on labels text
```

or

```
page.find(:label, for: 'user_subscribed_to_news').click #match on labels for attribute if set
```